# Proof of a limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I want to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+3n} = 2.$$
Is the following proof valid?

**Proof**

$\left|\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+3n} - 2\right|=\left|\frac{1-6n}{n^2+3n}\right| =\frac{6n-1}{n(n+3)} $ (because $n \in \mathbb N^+)$. $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)$
We have $n \ge 1 \implies 6n -1 > n + 3 \implies \frac{n+3}{n(n+3)} < \frac{6n-1}{n^2+3n}.$
Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.
Note that $ \frac{6n-1}{n^2+3n}< \epsilon \iff \frac{n+3}{n(n+3)} < \epsilon \iff n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}.$  $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (**)$
By the Archimedean Property of $\mathbb R$, $\exists N \in \mathbb N^+$ such that $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}.$
If $n \ge N$, then $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, and from $(*)$ and $(**)$ it follows that $\left|\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+3n} - 2\right| < \epsilon$.
Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+3n} = 2.$

Comment: $\frac{6n-1}{n^2+3n}< \epsilon \implies \frac{n+3}{n(n+3)} < \epsilon$ is not bidirectional since you used transitivity.

Comment: Fixable, but $6n-1\gt n+3$, though true, goes the wrong way. Use $6n-1\lt 6n$. Conclude that our absolute value is $\lt \frac{6}{n+3}$. Now picking $N$ should be easy.

Comment: So I choose $N$ to be > $\frac{6}{\epsilon} - 3$ and the proof will work?

Comment: Yes. Don't bother with the $-3$ part, if $N\gt 6/\epsilon$ we are certainly OK.

Comment: If you want are interested in the proof directly from the definition of limit, you can use ([tag:epsilon-delta]) tag. (And perhaps you might also mention this in the post.)

Answer (score 1):

From $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{2n^2+1}{n^2+3n}$, divide top and bottom by $n^2$ to get:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{2+1/n^2}{1+3/n}$, which, as $n\to\infty$ becomes

$\dfrac{2+0}{1+0}=\dfrac{2}{1}=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your “if and only if” are incorrect in
$$
\frac{6n-1}{n^2+3n}< \varepsilon \iff \frac{n+3}{n(n+3)} < \varepsilon \iff n > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}
$$
What you can do is
$$
n > \frac{6}{\varepsilon}\implies
\frac{6(n+3)}{n(n+3)}<\frac{6}{\varepsilon}\implies
\frac{6n-1}{n(n+3)}<\frac{6}{\varepsilon}
$$

---

*Alternative proof*

Rewrite your fraction as
$$
\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2+3n}=\frac{2n^2+6n-6n+1}{n^2+3n}=
2-\frac{6n-1}{n^2+3n}
$$
Now use partial fractions:
$$
\frac{6n-1}{n^2+3n}=\frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{n+3}
$$
can be easily solved to give $A=-1/3$ and $B=19/3$. So your expression is
$$
2+\frac{1/3}{n}-\frac{19/3}{n+3}
$$
Now fix $\varepsilon>0$ and find an integer $k$ such that
$$
\frac{1/3}{k}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\qquad
\frac{19/3}{k+3}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$
that is,
$$
k>\max\Bigl(\frac{2}{3\varepsilon},\frac{38}{3\varepsilon}-3\Bigr)
$$
and, for $n\ge k$ you have
$$
\left|\Bigl(2+\frac{1/3}{n}-\frac{19/3}{n+3}\Bigr)-2\right|=
\left|\frac{1/3}{n}-\frac{19/3}{n+3}\right|\le
\left|\frac{1/3}{n}\right|+\left|\frac{19/3}{n+3}\right|<
\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incorrect: you want to show that
$$\frac{6n-1}{n^2-3n}<\varepsilon$$
so what you need is
$$\frac{6n-1}{n^2-3n}<{\rm something}$$ or $6n-1<$something, that is an estimate of $6n-1$ from above, not from below.